# How to rebind item in RecyclerView when the data changed in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I customize a RecyclerView class which will display the content of `val backupItemList: List<MSetting>` in Kotlin in Code B

Now I modify the data of backupItemList outside  RecyclerView class, I think the Code D  will display the latest data in UI, but I failed, the UI is still to display old data.
I have to use Code C to display the latest data.

What's wrong with the Code D?

**Code A**

```
class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)                       

        allList= SettingHandler().getListAllSetting()            

        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        mCustomAdapter= CustomAdapter(allList)
        mRecyclerView.adapter= mCustomAdapter


   }


   public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
       //Code C          
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           allList=SettingHandler().getListAllSetting()
           mCustomAdapter= CustomAdapter(allList)
           mRecyclerView.adapter= mCustomAdapter
           mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
           mCustomAdapter.setSelectedItem(selectedBackupItem)  
       }


       //Code D     
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          allList=SettingHandler().getListAllSetting()                
          mCustomAdapter.setSelectedItem(selectedBackupItem)                
       }         

   }        

}
```

**Code B**

```
  class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

        val noRecord=-1
        private var mSelectedItem = noRecord

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(v)
        }

        fun getSelectedItem():Int{
            return  mSelectedItem
        }

        fun setSelectedItem(index:Int){
            if (index in 0..(backupItemList.size-1) ){
                mSelectedItem=index
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position])
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return backupItemList.size
        }

        inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {
                itemView.tvSubject.text=aMSetting.name
                itemView.tvCreatedDate.text=aMSetting.createdDate.toDateString()
                itemView.tvDescription.text=aMSetting.description   
                itemView.radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                mSelectedItem=adapterPosition
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if(adapterPosition == 0 && mSelectedItem == noRecord) {             
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked = true
                mSelectedItem=adapterPosition
            }
            else {
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked =(adapterPosition == mSelectedItem)
            }       
            }

        }

    }
```

**To civic.LiLister:**

Both Code C And Code D get the same result if I use Code E (I replace val with var),why?

**Code E**

```
  class CustomAdapter (var backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

        val noRecord=-1
        private var mSelectedItem = noRecord

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(v)
        }

        fun getSelectedItem():Int{
            return  mSelectedItem
        }

        fun setSelectedItem(index:Int){
            if (index in 0..(backupItemList.size-1) ){
                mSelectedItem=index
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position])
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return backupItemList.size
        }

        inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {
                itemView.tvSubject.text=aMSetting.name
                itemView.tvCreatedDate.text=aMSetting.createdDate.toDateString()
                itemView.tvDescription.text=aMSetting.description   
                itemView.radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                mSelectedItem=adapterPosition
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if(adapterPosition == 0 && mSelectedItem == noRecord) {             
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked = true
                mSelectedItem=adapterPosition
            }
            else {
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked =(adapterPosition == mSelectedItem)
            }       
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: please clear your point, where are you changing data, from the server?

Comment: From UI, I Edit allList via a UI

Comment: from another activity?

Comment: Yes. from another activity, and I use `public override fun onActivityResult` to handle result

Comment: clear onemore point, you want to add more items in list or edit the previously added items?

Comment: I edit  previously item

Comment: I think  the code `notifyDataSetChanged(); ` should rebind the items by modified allList, but in fact, the system doesn't do it

Comment: before adding a list to adapter in from onActivityResult(), clear the list and check and you can remove the notify.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me some sample code?

Comment: yes, @HelloCW as farhana said u have to clear list first and then you can add a new item to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The secret maybe hide here:

class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List)

When you init an instance of CustomAdapter, the value is copied to property backupItemList, rather than assigned the reference. Therefore, when you change property allList of UIMain, the backupItemList won't change as you expected.

The solution is simple, as Ganesh Tikone wrote: add an method to update backupItemList.

```
fun updateData(data: List<MovieModel>) {
    backupItemList.clear()
    backupItemList.addAll(data)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

and change Code D to:

```
//Code D     
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      allList=SettingHandler().getListAllSetting()  
      mCustomAdapter.updateData(allList)    
      mCustomAdapter.setSelectedItem(selectedBackupItem)                
   }
```

Have a try.

Comment: Thanks! please see my modified question, Code C and Code D get the same result when I use `class CustomAdapter (var backupItemList: List)`

Comment: When I init an instance of `CustomAdapter (var backupItemList: List)`, I think that a reference will be assigned to backupItemList, right?

Comment: And more, allList is List<MSetting> and it's not MutableList<MSetting>,  you can't invoke allList.clear() and allList.addAll()

Comment: Replace val with var for property backupItemList: List is not a good practice, I think. Though it works for your current project.
In functional programming, we should limit the usage of mutable data. We should try to make function pure. A var is something like a "global" variable. Which might be changed out of the adapter, and might cause strange bug that hard to fix.

Answer (score 6):

In your Activity onCreate method

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)                
    
            allList = ArrayList< MSetting>()
            mCustomAdapter = CustomAdapter(mChildList)
            mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            mRecyclerView.adapter = mCustomAdapter
    }
```

Now in onActivityResult

```
     public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {

           //Code C          
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              if(data != null){
                 allList.clear()
                 allList.addAll(SettingHandler().getListAllSetting())
                 mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                 mCustomAdapter.setSelectedItem(selectedBackupItem) 
              } 
           }
        
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code D, you are **overwriting the reference** for allList.

And the backupItemList in CustomAdapter has the reference for the same.
So if you reassign the reference for allList the changes will not be picked up in recycler view

first make sure allList is mutable

```
val allList = mutableListOf<MSetting>()
```

then in code D

```
allList.clear()
allList.addAll(SettingHandler().getListAllSetting())
mCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this code,

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           allList.clear()
           allList=SettingHandler().getListAllSetting()
           mCustomAdapter= CustomAdapter(allList)
           mRecyclerView.adapter= mCustomAdapter  
           mCustomAdapter.setSelectedItem(selectedBackupItem) 
       }
```

Comment: and remember to check your list in the log in `onActivityResult()` whether it has data or not.

Comment: Thanks! but your code just like my Code C, I think that maybe there is a better way

Comment: and I don't think you need to run `allList.clear()` because  `allList=SettingHandler().getListAllSetting()` will clear old data automatically

Comment: is onActivityResult()  returing RESULT_OK?

Comment: If I edit a record successfully in another activity, and I will assign RESULT_OK and return it to main activity

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are not using any `binding` which means when you modify `list`, `Adapter` won't be aware of that hence it simply displays old items, but once you notify `adapter` about changes in your list using `notifyDatasetChanged`, it will try to refresh items with new data. If you want to achieve functionality with `code D`, you need to use Data Binding using Observable pattern.For more information  [RecyclerView and Data Binding](https://medium.com/@ivan_m/data-binding-and-recyclerview-bf9a5d335a60)

Comment: I think the code `notifyDataSetChanged();` should rebind the items based modified allList, but in fact, the system doesn't do it

Comment: And more, could you show me some sample code to use Data Binding using Observable pattern about my question ?

Answer (score 2):

## Fragment Code

```
private var adapter: RecentMovieAdapter? = null
```

Adapter is initialized in onCreateView method of fragment

```
adapter = RecentMovieAdapter(activity, this)
```

This is callback method in Fragment, which gets data from Server using Threading technique

```
override fun onDataReceived(randomDialog: List<MovieModel>) {
    shimmerView!!.stopShimmerAnimation()
    shimmerView!!.visibility = View.GONE
    adapter!!.updateData(randomDialog)
}
```

## Adapter Class Code

```
private var movieList: MutableList<MovieModel> = mutableListOf<MovieModel>()
```

Add update function in Adapter class like this

```
fun updateData(data: List<MovieModel>) {
    movieList.clear()
    movieList.addAll(data)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yourAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged